# Stub static module method on controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mocking, stub, rspec3

```
allow_any_instance_of(ServicesController).to receive(A::B.auth(a, b, c, d)).and_return({value: true])
```

I cannot get my rspec test to mock method `A::B.auth`.

Using rspec 3 and rails 3.2. Test type: controller.

I want the mock to return a simple hash: `{value: true}`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
allow(A::B).to receive(:auth).and_return({value: true})
```